# Hibernate: First cascade missing after server restart

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

When I update my entity I keep track of the authors with `@PreUpdate` und `@PrePersist` and add an entry to my entity's authors history.

When I initially start my application the first ever change will **not** be cascaded, thus my authors-reference table will not have a new author included. Any subsequent changes are correctly persisted / cascaded. The annotated methods are correctly called. Any ideas? This behaviour is reproducible.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
   authors.add(new Author("update", ...));
}

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
   authors.add(new Author("create", ...));
}
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.5 and the spring framework for EM injection.